# Binning multiple arrays efficiently with the same bins

Tags: python, list, numpy, scipy, multiprocessing

The code below takes 12 seconds for num_iterations=1.

How can I make it faster (including using multiprocessing)? I want to be able to do this for num_iterations=1000.

I cannot find a sensible way for me to use multiprocessing because of the list of list structure - which is required as the number of elements in each bin is variable. Multiprocessing/memmap apparently do not work well with this structure.

```
import time
import numpy as np

idx = np.random.randint(int(1e6),size=int(1e7))
output = [[] for i in range(int(1e6))]
num_iterations = 1

t1=time.time()

for i in range(num_iterations):
    values = np.random.random(int(1e7))
    time.sleep(5)    # To account for the fact I need to load the data from disc.
    for j,value in enumerate(values):
        output[idx[j]].append(value)

print(time.time()-t1) # 12 seconds for num_iterations=1
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: nested loop has two same variables. Is this a typo or did you mean it that way?

Comment: sorry this was a type ehsan. Fixed in main body.

Comment: I have simplified the example @Quang Hoang. idx is a list of bin indices. I am then binning the values arrays into the corresponding bin.

Comment: So, you are trying 1000 times to append 10 million floats to lists. That will never fit into memory.  You really need to think about what you want to do with the result. And try to calculate that end-result on-the-fly without creating all those lists.

Comment: I do have supercomputer access. What I do with the end result is form 1d probability distributions from each list. So I suppose what I want to do is split the values array into parts. I was wondering with this question is if there was any sensible way to use memmap or shared memory to form it efficiently.

Comment: Well, this looks like a very inefficient use of super computer time. I think you should optimize it in C/C++ as it is mostly just moving numbers around. Storing the data on file in binary format shouldn't be doubted. What will you do with 1 million probability distributions?   You first need to run tests with much smaller (though meaningful) subsets. In Python, I would preprocess the idx array to allow for array assignments. But again, Python absolutely isn't suited for this size of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to note is that each time you map `values` to `output`, it is the same number of entries that are added for each bin. So, rather than appending to lists, you can pre-allocate numpy arrays with the correct size.

Moreover, you can store the indices for each bin in arrays (one array per bin). Since you only need to create these index arrays once for all the iterations, and since there are much fewer bins than values, you can pull all new entries out of `values` for one particular bin using:

```
output_chunk = values[indices]
```

Even faster is to use numba (this is included with the Anaconda Python distribution) for just-in-time (jit) compilation. Then you get performance similar to C without all the trouble of compiling and linking the code. I'm not sure about all the details of numba optimizations, but I think it's most efficient if a `@njit`-marked fuction uses only scalar variables and numpy arrays, not Python lists and dictionaries.

Here are the timings for three implementations (for a smaller array sizes than in your question):

```
%timeit -r2 -n5 f_reference(100)
486 ms ± 4.42 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 2 runs, 5 loops each)

%timeit -r2 -n50 f_vectorized(100)
73.6 ms ± 219 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 2 runs, 50 loops each)

%timeit -r2 -n50 f_numba(100)
9.6 ms ± 40.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 2 runs, 50 loops each)
```

Here is the implementation:

```
import numpy as np
import numba

np.random.seed(1)

n_vals = 10000 # 1e7
n_bins = 1000# 1e6

idx = np.random.randint(n_bins, size=n_vals)

def f_reference(n_iter):
    np.random.seed(2)
    output = [[] for i in range(n_bins)]
    for i in range(n_iter):
        values = np.random.random(n_vals) # simulate loading data
        for j,value in enumerate(values):
            output[idx[j]].append(value)    
    return [np.array(x) for x in output]

def f_vectorized(n_iter):
    np.random.seed(2)
    # each entry in bin_indices is an int array of indices into values
    # that belong in the corresponding bin.
    bin_indices = [np.where(idx==i)[0] for i in range(n_bins)]
    bin_sizes = [len(bi) for bi in bin_indices]
    output = [np.zeros(bs*n_iter) for bs in bin_sizes]
    
    for i in range(n_iter):
        values = np.random.random(n_vals) # simulate loading data
        for jbin, (indices, bsize) in enumerate(zip(bin_indices, bin_sizes)):
            output_chunk = values[indices]
            output[jbin][i*bsize:(i+1)*bsize] = output_chunk
    
    return output
    

@numba.njit
def _f_numba_chunk(i_chunk, idx, values, bin_sizes, bin_offsets, output_1):
    """Process one set of values (length n_vals).
    
    Update corresponding n_vals in output_1 array (length n_vals*n_iter).
    """
    # pointers to next entry for each bin, shape (n_bins,)
    j_bin_out = bin_offsets[:-1] + bin_sizes*i_chunk
    for i_bin, val in zip(idx, values):
        output_1[j_bin_out[i_bin]] = val
        j_bin_out[i_bin] += 1

def f_numba(n_iter):
    np.random.seed(2)
    bin_sizes, _ = np.histogram(idx, np.arange(n_bins+1)-0.5)
    bin_offsets = np.concatenate(([0], np.cumsum(bin_sizes)))*n_iter
    output_1 = np.empty(n_vals*n_iter)
    
    for i in range(n_iter):
        values = np.random.random(n_vals) # simulate loading data
        _f_numba_chunk(i, idx, values, bin_sizes, bin_offsets, output_1)
        
    # convert output_1 to list of arrays
    output = [
        output_1[bin_offsets[i]:bin_offsets[i+1]]
        for i in range(n_bins)
        ]
    
    return output

# test
out_ref = f_reference(5)
out_vec = f_vectorized(5)
out_numba = f_numba(5)


for oref, ovec, onum in zip(out_ref, out_vec, out_numba):
    assert np.all(ovec == oref)
    assert np.all(onum == oref)
```

With a factor 50 speedup, maybe it's not necessary anymore to parallellize this, but the part inside the loop `for i in range(n_iter)` can be parallellized using `multiprocessing.Pool`; each worker returns `output_chunk` and the top-level process only needs to store the chunks into `output`.